# Docusaurus: Swizzling or Root component overriding - For logo change

Tags: javascript, css, json, docusaurus

I made a website using docusaurus, in which I've defined its navbar as :

docusaurus.config.js file

```
  themeConfig:
    /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').ThemeConfig} */
    ({
        navbar: {
            title: "",
            logo: {
                alt: "Documentation Logo",
                srcDark:
                    "logolink1.png",
                src: "logoLink2.png",
            },
            items: [
                {
                    type: "custom-navbar",
                },
                {
                    to: "getting-started",
                    label: "Get Started",
                },
                {
                    to: "guides",
                    label: "Guides",
                },
                {
                    type: "custom-sidebarBottomMenu",
                },
                {
                    type: "custom-userAuthButtons",
                    position: "right",
                },
            ],
        },
        colorMode: {
            defaultMode: "dark",
            disableSwitch: true,
            respectPrefersColorScheme: false,
        },
    }),
```

Now on mobile view, I want to display another logo....I can't write media query here so, I did

> swizzle

... I referred to https://docusaurus.io/docs/swizzling and swizzled navbar__logo component by adding the overriding component in src/theme/Navbar/logo/index.js
In logo.js I have written the logic viz...

```
import React from "react";
import Logo from "@theme/Logo";
export default function NavbarLogo() {
    const isScreen = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches;

return (
    <Logo
        className="navbar__brand"
        imageClassName="navbar__logo"
        titleClassName="navbar__title text--truncate"
        src={
            isScreen
                ? "link1.png"
                : "link2.png"
        }
    />
);}
```

Please correct me if the logic is wrong is wrong or this code can be refactored...h

How do I edit my docusaurus.config file which is in json format...to take custom logo??

Answer (score 0):

Swizzling components is not a great idea with docusaurus. But sometimes that's the easiest way to achieve what is needed.

First you should look into solving your problem with css, docusaurus lets you style using custom css. https://docusaurus.io/docs/styling-layout

If the above doesn't work then you might want to swizzle the navbar if it's possible. It will create the component dir and add files to your src dir. https://docusaurus.io/docs/swizzling

Docusaurus has a few moving parts, the documentation in most cases will be your best friend.